# KeyError in template when key is definetly present

Tags: python, tornado

I want to render in template data like that: `[{'name': 'Some name', 'description': 'Description for this item'}]`

I try to use this code:

```
{% for item in source_data %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ item['name'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ item['description'] }}</td>
    </tr>
{% end %}
```

It doesn't work, because I receive `KeyError: 'description'` exception.

But if I change second placeholder to `{{ item.get('description') }}` it works as expected (Correct data from dictionary was printed, not default value).

What can produce this kind of error?

Comment: Please state, what templating language/framework you are using.

Comment: @aepsil0n there is a `tornado` tag :)

Comment: Oh, right... sorry I totally overlooked that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like not all of your dictionaries have `description` key.

Instead of directly getting the value by key, use dictionary [get()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method, that won't throw `KeyError` if a key wasn't found:

```
{% for item in source_data %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ item['name'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.get('description', 'No description') }}</td>
    </tr>
{% end %}
```

Demo:

```
>>> from tornado import template
>>> source_data = [
...     {'name': 'Some name', 'description': 'Description for this item'},
...     {'name': 'test'}
... ]

>>> template1 = template.Template("""
... {% for item in source_data %}
...     {{ item['description'] }}
... {% end %}
... """)

>>> template2 = template.Template("""
... {% for item in source_data %}
...     {{ item.get('description', 'No description found') }}
... {% end %}
... """)

>>> print template1.generate(source_data=source_data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "tornado/template.py", line 278, in generate
    return execute()
  File "<string>.generated.py", line 7, in _tt_execute
KeyError: 'description'
>>> print template2.generate(source_data=source_data)

    Description for this item

    No description found
```

Hope that helps.